# Macro expansion inside array

Tags: macros, expansion, arrays

I got stuck with the following piece of TeX:

```
\def\foo{A}
\def\bar{\foo}
\let\baz\bar
1: \baz
\def\foo{B}
\\
2: \baz
\\

\begin{array}[t]{r}
\def\foo{C}
3: \baz
\\
\def\foo{D}
4: \baz
\\
5: \baz
\end{array}

\begin{enumerate}
\def\foo{E}
\item[6:] \baz

\item[7:]
\def\foo{F}
\baz

\item[8:] \baz
\end{enumerate}
```

This piece of TeX is rendered as follows:

```
1: A
2: B

3: C
4: D
5: B

6: E
7: F
8: F
```

Now, lines 1 and 2 behave as expected, after redefining `\foo`, the new value is printed. However, when wrapped in an array, line 5 prints `B` where I would expect `D`. The macros work as expected when inside enumerate (lines 6-8).

How is it that line 5 prints as `B` instead of `D` and how to fix the definition of the macros?
I presume there is something weird going on with the expansion inside array. I tried to change array for align but that manifests the same problem.

Comment: Each element of the `array` is group scoped.  You need `\gdef` instead of `\def` to communicate outside of the group.

Comment: Blah, you are right, `gdef` works. Can you perhaps make this into a full answer and add some appropriate tex phrases? I seriously spent ages to try to figure this myself but it is very hard to google this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely expected

```
\def\foo{A}     % now \foo expands to A
\def\bar{\foo}  % now \bar expands to \foo
\let\baz\bar    % now \baz expands to \foo
1: \baz         % we get \foo, then A
\def\foo{B}     % now \foo expands to B
\\
2: \baz         % we get \foo, then B
\\

\begin{array}[t]{r}
\def\foo{C}     % now \foo expands to C
3: \baz         % we get \foo, then C
\\              % end of cell, \foo reverts to B
\def\foo{D}     % now \foo expands to D
4: \baz         % we get \foo, then D
\\              % end of cell, \foo reverts to B
5: \baz         % we get \foo, then B
\end{array}

\begin{enumerate}
\def\foo{E}     % now \foo expands to E
\item[6:] \baz  % we get \foo, then E

\item[7:]
\def\foo{F}     % now \foo expands to F
\baz            % we get \foo, then F

\item[8:] \baz  % we get \foo, then F
\end{enumerate}
```

Cells in `array` form groups. It's not clear what you want to achieve, but if you want that the definition of `\foo` transcends groups, you need `\gdef` rather than `\def`.

In particular, what's the role of `\bar`? You never use it, except when defining `\baz` as an alias to it.

Comment: You are right, it the groups. I had no idea cells form groups neither did it pop to me in any related question when I was trying to find a fix. I was writing a macro that issues a newline and prepends some text to it,whcih I want to change mid-array. After Steven's previous comment above I ended up with: `\def\baz{\gdef\foo{D}}`, `\def\qux{\gdef\foo{E}}` and `\def\NL{\newline\foo}`